# MS Visio trying to check the "End Arrow Type" for a connection between 2 shapes

Tags: .net, visio

I am attempting to pro grammatically (using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio) to read the shapes and connectors from a diagram and translate them.

[image: Example Arrow heads connected to Shapes]

I have managed to

- get each shape and the text i need from the shape.
- find each connector and get the shape at either end of the connector.

What I can't work out how to find is which arrow head is being used, the square or the black arrow (or others used in the diagram).

[image: The items I'm trying to find in the object model]

They appear like this in the UI but I can't seem to find the corresponding attribute(s) in the object model.

```
                   For Each iConnector As Shape In iPage.Shapes
                    If iConnector.Style = "Connector" Then
                        Dim lArc As New Arc
                        If iConnector.Connects.Count = 2 Then
                            Dim lLeft = iConnector.Connects.Item(1)
                            Dim lRight = iConnector.Connects.Item(2)
```

This gives the 2 connector points left and right. If you look at the "lLeft.FromCell.Name it will be called "EndX" or "BeginX" 
if you then look at the .ToSheet.Text you will see the text content of the shape at the beginning or end.

Does anyone know how to identify the Arrowhead from either the Connector shape OR from the Connect end?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For identify arrowhead type use

```
iConnector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineBeginArrow)  
iConnector.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineEndArrow)
```

You can find tutorial about connectors [there](https://translate.google.ru/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ru&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fvisio.getbb.ru%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D39%26t%3D1142&edit-text=&act=url)

Answer (score 0):

The article from @Surrogate is worth a read, as is [Drawing Visio Shapes from C-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/drawing-visio-shapes-in-the-visio-activex-control-using-C-Sharp-a/)

The actual answer to my specific question was

```
IF connector.Cells("EndArrow").Formula = "11" THEN
' you have the 11th arrowhead icon style.
```

NOTE: The Connector object here is of type Visio.Shape. You can identify the connector from the Shape.Style = "Connector" property.